# how to save image from this url via PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have URLs like this:

> https://strg.global/getImage.php?app=mgm&type=adinda-kennedy&imgId=MGM%20Adinda%20Kennedy%20e6057b8e-aa68-4461-8c9a-1d069fc021a4.jpg&size=1080&cachebreaker=1500536003696`

When you visit it the image downloads automatically.

How can I get and save it via PHP?

I've tried `file_get_content()`, but it returned info in inappropriate format for saving. 
I've tried to use Intervention image library and it's method  `Image::make($url)`, but it hasn't worked either.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the content from the URL, then create an image from the string you get back with (surprisingly) "imagecreatefromstring". After you have the image you can simply display it or save it  :

```
$Res = file_get_contents($URL);
$Img = imagecreatefromstring($Res);
imagepng($Img,"FileName.png");
imagedestroy($Img);
```

Comment: It does I tried it myself and saved the file as intended. just don't forget the "https.//" before the "strg...."